# Lorentz invariance and SR postulate

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, maxwell-equations

Probably a ridiculous question - why do we need to express Maxwell's equations in covariant form to show Lorentz invariance?
I mean, first SR postulate States that physical laws are same in inertial frames.

Wouldn't that simply mean Maxwell's equations are also same (just replace quantities as measured in New frame in the form of the equations)?

Comment: You seem to think that all physical laws are form-invariant under Lorentz transformations. Newtonian gravity isn’t. Since some laws are and some laws aren’t, isn’t it nice to have a notation that makes it *manifestly obvious* when they *are* form-invariant?

Comment: @G. Smith thanks for the comment. Could you please help me reconcile this with the first postulate which states physics is same in all inertial frames? Perhaps I'm misinterpreting something.

Comment: Newtonian gravity is not form-invariant under Lorentz transformations. This means that it is not a correct theory (although it is a very useful approximation for many purposes).

Comment: So that means if Maxwell's theory is a correct description of physics (and I get to know that somehow), it immediately follows it's form invariant, and vice versa. Isn't it?

Comment: Vice versa isn’t true. You can invent lots of theories which are form-invariant under Lorentz transformations but aren’t physically correct.

Comment: Is(are) there any theory in physics that has withstood experimental validation so far but is not form invariant?

Comment: Yes. For example, we don’t need relativistic equations to understand sound waves. Sound waves in air don’t involve anything moving anywhere hear the speed of light.

Answer (score 0):

We don't "need" to express Maxwell's laws in a manifestly Lorentz-covariant form. However when relating Maxwell's equations in one Lorentz frame to those of a boosted frame, it's typically easiest to work in a Lorentz covariant framework, since that's where the transformation equations are simplest.

Maxwell's equations in their standard non-Lorentz-covariant form are not so simple to relate from one frame to another. This is because electric and magnetic fields transform non-trivially into one another with Lorentz boosts. [See this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity#The_E_and_B_fields). Also you must transform the derivative operators appropriately according to the transformation formula $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} = \Lambda_\mu^\nu \frac{\partial}{\partial x'^\nu}$.